# Azure calls waiting a long time

Tags: blazor, azure-application-insights, stack-trace

From time to time our blazor application that is hosted in azure does not respond (sometimes more than 30sec) When I look into application insights I notice it is always waiting

[image: Waiting]

The problem is I don't find what it is waiting for. I suspect there is another thread taking a long time like when a user uploads a file, generates a docx file or pdf file I tried looking into the trace file with perfView and jit stats view seems best i think. There I notice long functions like

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

But I don't understand what this is, called by who or why it takes long. Some stack traces:

[trace1](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlfvUkxAeg9AhvhzEjLgZoDjCDiTGQ?e=7bVBoZ)

[trace2](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlfvUkxAeg9Ahvh08R2JUlu5akTHow?e=8BbMDv)

[trace3](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlfvUkxAeg9AhvhyvYUxcrESGzvUkg?e=fyVKVx)

Can someone point me in the direction where to look?

Answer (score 0):

***The stack traces you've provided can offer valuable insights into the execution flow of the application and help identify potential bottlenecks. Look for patterns in the stack traces, including the functions and methods being called, to understand which parts of the application are contributing to the delays***

- Install and configure a local development environment that mirrors the configuration of the Azure hosting environment.

Ensure that necessary dependencies, tools, and frameworks are installed for local development and testing.

**Focus on identifying the specific operations or tasks within the application that are taking a long time to complete. This might include file uploads,**

- Run the Blazor application locally and simulate the actions or operations that trigger performance delays observed in the Azure environment.

Use browser developer tools or Visual Studio's performance profiler to monitor and analyze performance metrics during local testing.

***Reference:***

- [Application insights logs are taking a lot of time to appear in azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/800298/application-insights-logs-are-taking-a-lot-of-time)

Comment: I tried all that and dont notice any problems locally.
Like I said the file functions like the generation can take a while so I was wondering that one of those functions blocks other user threads on the server.
Locally I connect alone so there are not other calling threads.
I wanted to split those generation functions into different service but I wanted to be sure those are the problem but I don't see them in the stack traces

Comment: consider isolating the file generation functions into separate services or background processes. This can help offload the heavy processing to dedicated resources, it doesn't directly impact the responsiveness of your web application.